# Twig conditions for node/page/view in page-title.html

Tags: theming

I am trying to set different classes in the page-title.html.twig based on what drupal is actually showing. The first condition works in a node template, but not in the page-title.html. This is a pseudo-code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'title--h1',
    node.type.entity.label == 'Blogpost' ? 'ico ico--time',
    page.machine_name == 'about_me' ? 'ico ico--world',
    view.machine_name == 'blogpost_list' ? 'ico ico--target'
  ]
%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your `MYTHEME.theme`. This will provide the machine name value to your `page.html.twig` template files.

**MYTHEME.theme**:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page($variables) {
  $variables['machine_name'] = $variables['page']['#type'];
}
```

Then in **page.html.twig**:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    'title--h1',
    machine_name == 'about_me' ? 'ico ico--world',
  ]
%}
```

`{{ machine_name }}`

For **node.html.twig** templates, use bundle to get the machine name:

```
{%
  set classes = [
    node.bundle == 'content__type' ? 'one-class' : 'another-class'
  ]
%}
```

You cannot access the bundle type in `MYTHEME_preprocess_page_title()` directly.